# Android XML parsing issues using SAX parser

Tags: android, xml-parsing, android-xml

I am parsing an XML file from assets folder to dump my data into the database. Later on i may fetch this and display it in a text view. But while parsing i am losing some data, ie, if i have some 50 words within the XML tags before parsing, in my database i am not able to find all of them after parsing.

For exmple:
I am parsing this line:

```
<about>Skandagiri also known as kalavara durga, is an ancient mountain fortess located approximately 70km from Banglore city and 3 km from Chikkaballapur in the Indian State of Karnataka.It is off Bellary road(NH 7, Hyderabad to Bangalore Highway) and overlooks Nandi Hills, Mudddenahalli and Kanive narayanapura.The peak is at an altitude of about 1350 meters</about>
```

after parsing in my database:

```
at an altitude of about 1350
```

i am using String to hold my parsed value like this:

```
if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("about")){
  String str=parsedValue;
}
```

Comment: What datatype is the database column that you store the string in, and what is the size of it?

Comment: Without seeing your parsing code I can just guess: the SAX parser may deliver the content in chunks that you have to concatenate. You seem to return just the last chunk.

Comment: you might be right, but when i delete the last line , ie if i only put this line i am getting correct string::::Skandagiri also known as kalavara durga, is an ancient mountain fortess located approximately 70km from Banglore city and 3 km from Chikkaballapur in the Indian State of Karnataka.It is off Bellary road(NH 7, Hyderabad to Bangalore Highway) and overlooks Nandi Hills, Mudddenahalli and Kanive narayanapura.

Comment: Do you get the whole string if you try to print it to LogCat before inserting it into the database?

Comment: No. I am not getting the whole string. i am getting the wrong log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a StringBuffer, since text can be read in chunks and you may be reading just the part of code.
use string buffer and append all the chunks, so that finally you will get the complete text without missing out any data.

Like this:

```
StringBuffer strbufr = new StringBuffer();

    if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("about")){
      String str = strbufr.toString().trim();
    }  

    @Override
        public void characters(char[] ac, int i, int j) throws SAXException {
            strbufr.append(ac, i, j);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SAXparser than it is better to wrap the data with StringBuffer.
Take a look in oficial documentation : [ContentHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html).
Here is the interesting part from it :

> The Parser will call this method to report each chunk of character data. SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the characters in any single event must come from the same external entity so that the Locator provides useful information.

Comment: I used string buffer in this way, but still the prob exists. Am i using the string buffer correctly?:::if (element.equalsIgnoreCase("about")) {
   StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer();
   strbuf.append(parsedValue);
    String str=strbuf.toString();
  }

Comment: You need to append to StringBuffer on "characters( char[] ch, int start, int length )"

Comment: I am unable to solve this problem. Could you please help?;;;public void characters(char[] ac, int i, int j) throws SAXException {
  StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer();
  strbuf.append(new String(ac, i, j));
  parsedValue = strbuf.toString();
 }

Comment: You need to APPEND ch to object that was already created outside the function,otherwise you just creating it each time with current values.

Answer (score 2):

Plaese try Below code..I think solved your issue.

```
  Element element = (Element) node.item(i);

  NodeList id = element.getElementsByTagName("about");
  Element line1 = (Element) id.item(0);
  if (null != line1)

      AdsFound[i] = getCharacterDataFromElement(line1);

  else

      AdsFound[i] = "";
```